# Codeigniter using LIKE with WHERE in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

In codeigniter , I have a query like this:

```
    $this->db->select('*', false);
    $this->db->from('video as v');
    $this->db->where('v.start_date <=', 'NOW()', false);
    $this->db->like('v.title', $keywords);
    $this->db->or_like('v.title_tw', $keywords);
    $this->db->or_like('v.title_cn', $keywords);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

In my expectation:

```
start_date <= NOW **AND** title like $keywords OR title_tw like $keywords OR title_cn like $keywords
```

However, it turn out to be:

```
start_date <= NOW **OR** title like $keywords OR title_tw like $keywords OR title_cn like $keywords
```

How to fix that? Thanks a lot.

Update:

Actual query:

```
function search_video($keywords) {
    $this->db->select('v.*,t.name,t.name_tw,t.name_cn, t.image_url as profile_pic, COALESCE(b.duration, bt.duration, bc.duration) AS duration, COALESCE(b.thumbnail, bt.thumbnail, bc.thumbnail) as thumbnail', false);
    $this->db->from('video as v');
    $this->db->join('teacher as t', 'v.teacher_id = t.id');
    $this->db->join('video_tag as vt', 'v.id = vt.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as b', 'v.video = b.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as bt', 'v.video_tw = bt.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as bc', 'v.video_cn = bc.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('v.is_delete', false);
    $this->db->where('v.start_date <=', 'NOW()', false);
    $this->db->like('v.title', $keywords);
    $this->db->or_like('v.title_tw', $keywords);
    $this->db->or_like('v.title_cn', $keywords);
    $this->db->or_like('vt.tag', $keywords);
    $this->db->group_by('v.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For CodeIgniter 3.x:

You can use [Query grouping](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) to use parentheses in query:

```
    $this->db->select('v.*,t.name,t.name_tw,t.name_cn, t.image_url as profile_pic, COALESCE(b.duration, bt.duration, bc.duration) AS duration, COALESCE(b.thumbnail, bt.thumbnail, bc.thumbnail) as thumbnail', false);
        $this->db->from('video as v');
        $this->db->join('teacher as t', 'v.teacher_id = t.id');
        $this->db->join('video_tag as vt', 'v.id = vt.video_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('brightcove as b', 'v.video = b.video_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('brightcove as bt', 'v.video_tw = bt.video_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('brightcove as bc', 'v.video_cn = bc.video_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('v.is_delete', false);
        $this->db->where('v.start_date <=', 'NOW()', false);
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('v.title', $keywords);
        $this->db->or_like('v.title_tw', $keywords);
        $this->db->or_like('v.title_cn', $keywords);
        $this->db->or_like('vt.tag', $keywords);
        $this->db->group_end();
        $this->db->group_by('v.id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

> For CodeIgniter 2.x:

while I haven't tested it, I've just thought this should work:

```
$this->db->select('v.*,t.name,t.name_tw,t.name_cn, t.image_url as profile_pic, COALESCE(b.duration, bt.duration, bc.duration) AS duration, COALESCE(b.thumbnail, bt.thumbnail, bc.thumbnail) as thumbnail', false);
    $this->db->from('video as v');
    $this->db->join('teacher as t', 'v.teacher_id = t.id');
    $this->db->join('video_tag as vt', 'v.id = vt.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as b', 'v.video = b.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as bt', 'v.video_tw = bt.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as bc', 'v.video_cn = bc.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('v.is_delete', false);
    $this->db->where('v.start_date <=', 'NOW()', false);
    $this->db->where("( v.title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'", null, FALSE);
    $this->db->or_like('v.title_tw', $keywords);
    $this->db->or_like('v.title_cn', $keywords);
    $this->db->where("OR vt.tag LIKE '%{$keywords}%' )", null, FALSE);
    $this->db->group_by('v.id');
```

Comment: thanks , but found the current codeigniter is 2.x.x, any workaround for that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM video as v where v.start_date <= NOW() AND (v.title like ? OR v.title_tw like ? or v.title_cn like ?);
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($keywords, $keywords, $keywords));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping. the problem is the actual query is quite complicate so using the one line query may not be that simple

Comment: @user782104 - Ok, I see your new edit with the actual query. You should still be able to define the full SQL query with `?` parameters representing each of the `$keywords` input and use the `db->query()` method as everything else is static. Perhaps an option anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I create the query like this, seems work fine:

```
function search_video($keywords) {
    $this->db->select('v.*,t.name,t.name_tw,t.name_cn, t.image_url as profile_pic, COALESCE(b.duration, bt.duration, bc.duration) AS duration, COALESCE(b.thumbnail, bt.thumbnail, bc.thumbnail) as thumbnail', false);
    $this->db->from('video as v');
    $this->db->join('teacher as t', 'v.teacher_id = t.id');
    $this->db->join('video_tag as vt', 'v.id = vt.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as b', 'v.video = b.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as bt', 'v.video_tw = bt.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('brightcove as bc', 'v.video_cn = bc.video_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where("(v.is_delete = false AND v.start_date <= NOW()) AND (v.title LIKE '$keywords' OR  v.title_tw LIKE '$keywords' OR v.title_cn LIKE '$keywords' OR vt.tag LIKE '$keywords')");
    $this->db->group_by('v.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Thanks a lot for helps.